# Why is my datatable adding a blank row?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am hitting a controller and passing back an array which i loop through and then pass into a datatable.

When i first pass data into the datatable, for some reason it is adding a blank row, although if i then clear the table, and add exactly the same data, it doesn't.

I'm not doing anything fancy, just a really basic DT.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#workcarriedouttable').dataTable().fnAddData([
                    data[i].DateStarted,
                    data[i].TimeStarted,
                    data[i].DateEnded,
                    data[i].TimeEnded,
                    data[i].WorkDetails,
                    data[i].WorkCost
                ]);
            }
```

I have stepped through my code and the array does not contain any blank records, so i assume this is happening only when the DT is first initialized.

Which is simply

```
$('#workcarriedouttable').dataTable()
```

Table structur

```
<table id="workcarriedouttable" class="display">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width:30px;">Date Start</th>
                                    <th style="width:30px;">Time Start</th>
                                    <th style="width:30px;">Date End</th>
                                    <th style="width:30px;">Time End</th>
                                    <th style="width:240px;">Details</th>
                                    <th style="width:30px;">Cost</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Does your #workcarriedouttable have an empty tr element in it to start?

Comment: never mind, ive generated the table when i initialize the table and this resolved the issue